# Convert .STP (STEP) to usable format on MAC

Tags: 3d, autocad, cad, step

How do I convert a .STP (STEP) file to a format which I can use on MAC Autocad? I have an .STP file which I want to open in Autocad on MAC but MAC doesnt support .STP files. MAybe I need to convert in .STL?

Comment: You will need to convert the STEP file to a file format supported by AutoCAD. Depending on the version of AutoCAD you have, it might contain the import STEP function as described here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-mechanical/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Mechanical/files/GUID-296E2394-E9FB-46DC-9E34-997CA508CE46-htm.html

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

1) Actually OS (MAC) does not support file format, Autocad does (or not).

2) there are many STEP formats (standards ISO) depending on AP. for example AP203, AP214, AP242, etc.

did you ry both to open and import your file in Autocad? Usually for CAD applilcation,, Open deals with the propriatary formats, rather than import deal with other formats.

Other idea: rename the ".stp" extension in ".step"